# Prolog: Can assign a valiable on a value based on this matching condition (ANAGRAM)

Tags: prolog

Here is a prolog program that can link a number from one list to a letter from another list based on them having matching positions in their respective lists.

So for example, you have a word 'listen' and a number 321645
I have a fuction, split that splits these words and numbers up into tables and then a function assign_map that assigns them together (which doesnt work how I want currently)

```
split( '', [] ).
split(W,X):- atom_chars(W,X).

assign_map(A, B, LM):-
  split(A, LA),
  split(B, LB),
  maplist(map, LA, LB, LM).
  
map(A,B, A = B).
```

**The problem:** I need the the letters to be assigned to a variable.
For example, the letter 'L' would match with the number 3
so I want L to be assigned to a variable PosThree and then the same for the rest of the letters.
**Any help would be appreciated, thank you**

Answer (score -1):

Here is my attempt, you can add facts:

```
split( '', [] ).
split(W,X):- atom_chars(W,X).

assignNum(A,B):-
    split(A,LA),
    split(B,LB),
    splitNum(LA,LB).

variable('0','PosZero').
variable('1','PosOne').
variable('2','PosTwo').
variable('3','PosThree').
variable('4','PosFour').
variable('5','PosFive').
variable('6','PosSix').
variable('7','PosSeven').
variable('8','PosEight').
variable('9','PosNine').


splitNum([H|T],[H2|T2]):-
       variable(H2,L),
        write(L),    
        write('='),
        writeln(H),
      splitNum(T,T2).

?-assignNum(listen,327654).
PosThree=l
PosTwo=i
PosSeven=s
PosSix=t
PosFive=e
PosFour=n
false

?-assignNum(award,82156).
PosEight=a
PosTwo=w
PosOne=a
PosFive=r
PosSix=d
false
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, That's not exactly it, what I need is for it to be variable(L, PosThree) so the letter is assigned to the variable but based on the number that is next to it

Comment: You mean variable('L','PosThree').? Can you tell me what is the output suppose to be?

Comment: The output doesn't really matter but yes like you say, variable('L','PosThree'). so the output of that would be true. But, the main thing is L is assigned to PosThree because the number 3 and the Letter 'L' are in the same position in their lists

Comment: so for example I have listen and 327654, so L and 3 should be PosOne, i and 2 should be PosTwo ..... and so on?

Comment: actually L is PosThree because L matches with the number 3, as the number 3 and the Letter L are in the same point in their lists

Comment: PosThree=[L,3]. Do you think this will sense?

Comment: maybe, but how does the program know to save L to PosThree?